# NodeJs - Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I am trying to use godaddy ssl certificates on ec2. But getting this error.

**Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line**

Flow I used.

- openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout foo.com.key -out
  foo.com.csr
- used foo.com.csr to generate the **godaddy** and got 3 files.

  **3b8bc5516b18ff0.crt** , **3b8bc5516b18ff0.pem** and **gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt**

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('3b8bc5516b18ff0.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('3b8bc5516b18ff0.crt');
/**
* And converted gd_bundele to gd0, gd1, gd2
*/
var credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('gd0.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('gd1.crt'),
    fs.readFileSync('gd2.crt')
  ]
};


//http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .

1. openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout foo.com.pem -out foo.com.csr
2. foo.com.pem should be passed as privatekey.

NOTE : It is important save the key with which the csr was created and sent to the godaddy (I called foo.com.pem).

Comment: *"...save the key with which the csr was created and __sent to the godaddy__...*" - you should not sent your private key to the CA but only the CSR. The __private key should be kept private__ as its name suggests.